# É possível criar um campo dinâmico dentro de um Advanced Custom Field?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-types

Preciso criar um campo ***dinâmico*** puxando informações do banco de dados que estará relacionando professores e suas características e colocar esse campo como ***ACF [Advanced Custom Fields]*** dentro de um ***CPT UI [Custom Post Type]*** chamado professores.

A única coisa que eu preciso saber é como criar esse campo dinâmico.

Provavelmente será através de uma **função** dentro do `functions.php` que vai relacionar estes dados e depois ativar o `get_field` dentro do ***CPT*** artigos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível, sim. Vai precisar incluir JavaScript/jQuery nessa página e "escutar" mudanças no dropdown. As mudanças vão disparar chamadas Ajax e atualizar o Meta Box do ACF dinamicamente.

Não é pouco código nem simples. O ACF também tem umas nomenclaturas bem específicas para os *boxes* e *fields* que cria no *backend*, e vai precisar inspecionar o DOM com cuidado para saber os IDs corretos.

Este aqui é um exemplo *muito próximo* do que precisa: [Display live preview of page on hover in WP admin using ACF relationship field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26065301/1287812).

Outros dois relacionados:

- [Only allow new subpages to be created](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/59987/12615)
- [Unattaching images from a post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54875/12615)

<sub>PS: é muito importante criar seus próprios plugins para fazer este tipo de coisa, e **não o `functions.php`**; na hora que resolver mudar de *theme*, vai agradecer muito. Na hora de procurar bugs também. Vide: [Where do I put the code snippets I found here or somewhere else on the web?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72183/12615)</sub>